# Gradle: Cannot run SQL Script due to not having correct permissions?

Tags: java, oracle, gradle, oracle11g, triggers

I have added the following `SQL` script to be ran by `Gradle` within my Project:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
        BEFORE update of ID ON person
        FOR each row
     BEGIN
        :new.updated := systimestamp;
     END;;
```

When the [DBDeploy](https://codeborne.com/2012/09/27/using-dbdeploy-in-gradle.html) task tries to run this script, I get the error that the script can't be ran as the user does not have the required `permissions`?

How can I fix this within my `Gradle` scripts?

Comment: is your DBDeploy task logging in as the schema that owns the person table when it runs the script?

Comment: Add the error message to the question please. I assume the used DB user does not have rights to add/modify triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within a database session that has "powerful" privileges (the most powerful is `SYSDBA`), you should grant the permissions to "create a trigger" to that database user (the user you are connecting from gradle) like below:

```
-- if the user used in gradle is the same user that owns the schema, like it seems
grant CREATE TRIGGER to <the user>;

-- if the user used in gradle is a different user, you must grant him a more powerful right:
grant CREATE ANY TRIGGER;
```

Then issue the command from gradle (remember that if they are two different users you have to specify the schema in which the user resides)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER the_schema.my_trigger...
```

There are several other privileges that can be granted to permit the creation of a trigger (like `GRANT resource to...`) but the ones above are the most restrictive ones that work for your purpose (in order not to grant additional unnecessary rights).